# angular-nvd3-directives: Even distribution of unequal intervals on the X axis in a cumulative line chart

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

This is what I currently have: http://plnkr.co/edit/t9Ulhk5wK4ymnsahn2uf

I am not able to get the intervals on the X axis - 50, 500, 5000 - to be evenly distributed.

I tried a few approaches, but I am missing something. Here's one that isn't working...

In the HTML:

```
  <nvd3-cumulative-line-chart
          data="data"
          id="exampleId"
          width="400"
          height="250"
          xAxisScale="xAxisScaleFunction()"
          xAxisDomain="xAxisDomainFunction()" 
          xAxisRange="xAxisRangeFunction()"
          showXAxis="true"
          showYAxis="true"
          tooltips="true"
          interactive="true"
          color="colorFunction()"
          legendColor="colorFunction()"
          forcey="[0, 1]"
          showLegend="true"
          margin="{left:50,top:50,bottom:50,right:50}"
          useInteractiveGuideLine="true"
          xAxisTickValues="[50, 500, 5000]"
          >
      <svg></svg>
  </nvd3-cumulative-line-chart>
```

And in my controller:

```
  $scope.xAxisScaleFunction = function() {
    return d3.scale.ordinal();
  };

  $scope.xAxisDomainFunction = function() {
    return [50, 500, 5000];
  };

  $scope.xAxisRangeFunction = function() {
    return [0, 200, 400];
  };
```